# Partly server-side rendering

Tags: javascript, web, reactjs, redux

We know server-side rendering is good for SEO, especially for some blog app. But it will loose some good ux feature and not easy to debug comparing to the client-side rendering app.

I am wondering if there is way to apply the server-side rendering technique partly on the parts of a web app (like the blog part of the app), but using the client-side rendering for the rest. Kinda mix the server-side and client-side rendering together. Not sure this is what the isomorphic app means.

Comment: "But it will loose some good ux feature". Why do you say that?

Comment: I admit that I had heard this saying somewhere before but had verified that. I might be wrong. But for some server website I found, the first page load is wonky

Answer (score 2):

Isomorphic JavaScript(aka Universal JavaScript) can do that. You can make a web application that the first rendering comes from the server-side, and all activities after that are rendered by the client-side. Please be noted that the both sides share the same code.